# Unwanted artifacts in Dynamic Paint wetmap

Tags: texture-baking, dynamic-paint

I have been trying to get the effect of melted wax running down the surface of someone's face. [image: render created using fluid sim]

After struggling to recreate the desired viscosity with a fluid sim, I decided to used Dynamic Paint with the drip effect to create an image sequence of wet maps.[image]

The results were much better, however, there are some messy artifacts that ruin the illusion (as seen on the nose).[image: Wet map image texture rendered at 4k] After rendering the image sequence at various resolutions with the same result, I have a feeling that this is due to the simulation side of Dynamic Paint. Is there any way to correct this? If not, is there another approach I can take to get the same effect?